# Thanks for Participating in the 2016 Community Day

Tags: discussion

## Thanks for participating!

Thanks to everyone who came out and participated in Community Day! It looks like we answered around **42~** questions and closed around **111~** off-topic questions which pushes our answer rate up 1% from 72% to **73%**. It's a small but meaningful jump that will hopefully keep getting better and better.

For those who did show up, what were your thoughts on the event? How can we improve this type of event in the future? What would you like to see next?

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, but I want to keep chipping away at these. Seems like a *day* is not enough for a task this big.

Comment: @DaveRomsey No worries – there will be another chance.

Comment: Good work team. We now beat StackOverflow on the answered rate! ;)